# R: Splitting Data Into All Possible "Factor" Combinations

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

vars <- list(c("A","B"), c("AA","BB", "CC"), c("AA1","BB1"))
probs <- list(c(0.3, 0.7), c(0.2, 0.1, 0.7), c(0.5, 0.5))

setNames(map2_dfc(vars, probs, ~ .x |> sample(1000, replace=TRUE, prob=.y) |> as.factor()), paste0("var_", 1:3)) |> 
  mutate(var_4 = rnorm(1000,10,10),
         var_5 = rnorm(1000,10,10),
         var_6 = rnorm(1000,10,10))

# A tibble: 1,000 × 6
   var_1 var_2 var_3  var_4 var_5 var_6
   <fct> <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     CC    BB1   10.8    4.68  6.24
 2 B     CC    AA1    9.49   6.30  8.86
 3 B     CC    AA1    7.39  21.7  12.9 
 4 B     CC    AA1   25.7    5.35 24.6 
 5 A     BB    BB1    6.28   6.98 19.9 
 6 B     CC    BB1   27.4   23.9  15.6 
 7 A     CC    BB1   -0.989  5.50 19.4 
 8 A     CC    AA1   18.7    1.53 12.6 
 9 B     CC    BB1   15.3    9.67 -2.20
10 B     AA    AA1   -3.94  11.5  16.4 
# ℹ 990 more rows
```

**My Question:** In the above data, there are 3 factor variables with a total of 12 possible combinations of these factors. I am trying to extract each of these combinations and create 12 new datasets, dedicated to each one of these combinations.

I tried the following code in R:

```
lst1 <- split(my_data, my_data[c("var_1", "var_2", "var_3")], drop = TRUE)
```

I then tried to extract each of these dataset form this list:

```
list2env(lst1,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

**Can someone please tell me if what I have done is correct? If there were more variables and more factor combinations - is there a more efficient way to solve this problem?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking if there are better ways to split out the data, then there's nothing wrong with your approach.  Except it's not advisable to add the individual lists to the global environment, rather keep them in the list.  It might be helpful to share what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: Why do you need to split into separate data frames? Could any processing be done using aggregated functions with, e.g. data.table. For example `library(data.table); dtcars <- data.table(mtcars); dtcars[, mean(mpg), keyby=.(cyl, am)]`

Comment: `split` is the standard way to split a data frame by levels of one or more grouping variables, and `list2env` is the standard way to multi-assign from a named list into an environment. If that is what you want to accomplish, then your code is reasonable, provided you want 1 data frame per _observed_ combination. Any of the possible 12 combinations could be unobserved by chance. In this case, you would end up with fewer than 12 data frames.